# How to open devtools in Blink.jl

Tags: julia

How do I open devtools when using Blink.jl?

```
using Blink

opts = Dict("webPreferences" => Dict("devTools" => "true"))
w = Window(opts, async=true)
```

https://juliagizmos.github.io/Blink.jl/latest/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open devtools with:

```
opentools(win)
```